# How to achieve redundancy and failover strategy for Redis backed server

Tags: redis, load-balancing, redundancy

I have a web/mobile app for food delivery. The thing is, my server does a lot more **writes** than **reads** to the database. Right now I'm running a PostgreSQL and the problem is that a lot of the server requests happen in short periods of time(around noon and at evening), so I need various instances(plus S3 for backup) to be able to achieve the **writes** throughput, which I think is not anything close to good because the things are scaling and these PG instances will seem like rabbits reproducing.

My constraints:

- Much more **writes** than **reads**
- Approximately 25.000 req/s in **writes** and growing
- I need a guarantee of strong consistency for the data while not processed(consumers orders checked by restaurant) after registered in the system(**write** in the database)
- It is preferable to not have a service running than to have a faulty one (sacrifice availability in favor of consistency)

Doing some benchmarks with my production servers, Redis is capable of handling 1.5x my current peaks with only 1 server, and has a `List` structure that would be very useful for managing the orders queue.

I read that Redis, out of the box with Sentinel/Cluster is not able to provide strong consistency, so, to achieve this, I thought of doing one of these 2 things:

1. Set Sentinel with 3 instances(1 Master and 2 Slaves) with `Wait` and `appendfsync always` policies configured and check in the client when `Wait` returns less than 2. This way, the Sentinel will take care of replication and failover and with the help of my server it would always maintain strong consistency.
2. The second option is to have the same 3 instances with the `appendfsync always`, but to simply apply a software RAID 1 in these 3 through my application server, but in this way, I would have to think in a control logic to achieve redundancy and failover capabilities. The problems would be when trying to scale my application(node.js) behind a proxy, because in order to provide full redundancy I would have to manage the attempts of writes in each Redis instance, and if this application goes down, the other one may not know if the 3 are in sync and what is the latest data to sync.

From my point of view, the second option seems more robust than the first, because in this I can only loose 1 server, while in the second option I can use any of the 3, provided that I guarantee consistency.

What am I missing? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> Much more writes than reads
>   Approximately 25.000 req/s in writes and growing

Did you look Cassandra (https://cassandra.apache.org/), If you don't need change data structure regulary, it may be good choice for you.

> I read that Redis, out of the box with Sentinel/Cluster is not able to provide strong consistency

Yes, it's true.

If your have 25.000 writes/s, `WAIT` and `appendfsync always` is not good choice.

Regards,